# PHP: Equivalent of include using eval

Tags: php, include, eval

If the code is the same, there appears to be a difference between:

`include 'external.php';`

and

`eval('?>' . file_get_contents('external.php') . '<?php');`

What is the difference? Does anybody know?

---

I know the two are different because the `include` works fine and the `eval` gives an error. When I originally asked the question, I wasn't sure whether it gave an error on all code or just on mine (and because the code was `eval`ed, it was very hard to find out what the error meant). However, after having researched the answer, it turns out that whether or not you get the error does not depend on the code in the `external.php`, but does depend on your php settings (`short_open_tag` to be precise).

Comment: Thanks for this question. It helped with this: https://github.com/tedivm/Stash/pull/135

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some more research I found out what was wrong myself. The problem is in the fact that `<?php` is a "short opening tag" and so will only work if `short_open_tag` is set to 1 (in php.ini or something to the same effect). The correct full tag is `<?php`, which has a space after the second p.

As such the proper equivalent of the include is:

```
eval('?>' . file_get_contents('external.php') . '<?php ');
```

Alternatively, you can leave the opening tag out all together (as noted in the comments below):

```
eval('?>' . file_get_contents('external.php'));
```

My original solution was to add a semicolon, which also works, but looks a lot less clean if you ask me:

```
eval('?>' . file_get_contents('external.php') . '<?php;');
```

Comment: isn't eval("?>".file_get_contents('external.php')); the same as include 'external.php'; ??

Comment: YuriKolovsky, you are right leaving out the the php-opening tag is an alternative to following it up with a semicolon.

Comment: may i ask why you appended '?>' and '<?php;' ? Btw, Mine produced an error when I used '<?php;'. I fixed it by removing the 'php' part.

Comment: @kapitanluffy: include processes the file, which means it starts in "text mode" (as opposed to "php mode", where in php mode the code is executed and in "text mode" the text is simply copied to the output), while eval starts in "php mode". I dropped out of php mode in the eval case so it would do the same as include.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK you can't take advantage of php accelerators if you use eval().

Comment: AFAIK you have to have a real file on filesystem.

Comment: ...and you shouldn't be concerned about it unless you have performance problem.

Comment: I meant that AFAIK php accelerators only work with real files on filesystem. Building for php accelerators will most likely complicate your code (you have to check if files are writable etc.) and it is possible it wouldn't make any visible improvement. If they're just template files, my guess is that it won't change anything.

Comment: @niteria Just wanted to point out that you say AFAIK too much.

Comment: I decided to remove (my part of) the discussion that was taking up way too much space here. This answer answers the original phrasing of the question, though I don't believe it answers the essence of it (which remained the same). The discussion was also about things not in the question ([stream wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php)). Finally, the point about being wary of the inability to use an opcode cache (and since php 5.5 there's one built-in in php) with eval is a good one, though it might be more of a comment than an answer with the current phrasing.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a webserver on which you have installed an opcode cache, like [APC](http://php.net/apc), `eval` will not be the "*best solution*" : eval'd code is not store in the opcode cache, if I remember correctly *(and another answer said the same thing, btw)*.

A solution you could use, at least if the code is not often changed, is get a mix of code stored in database and included code :

- when necessary, fetch the code from DB, and store it in a file on disk
- include that file
- as the code is now in a file, on disk, opcode cache will be able to cache it -- which is better for performances
- and you will not need to make a request to the DB each time you have to execute the code.

I've worked with software that uses this solution (the on-disk file being no more than a cache of the code stored in DB), and I worked not too bad -- way better that doing loads of DB requests of each page, anyway...

Some not so good things, as a consequence :

- you have to fetch the code from the DB to put it in the file "when necessary"

  - this could mean re-generating the temporary file once every hour, or deleting it when the entry in DB is modified ? Do you have a way to identify when this happens ?
- you also have to change your code, to use the temporary file, or re-generate it if necessary

  - if you have several places to modifiy, this could mean some work

*BTW : would I dare saying something like "eval is evil" ?*

Comment: I'm sorry but your suggestion is completely irrelevant. I am writing some software and I made it so that it would only use files. I wanted to provide an alternative by the use of a database for when writing files is not an option, thus I ended up with this.
However, we are only talking about one db query and one eval statement. And the speed is not all that bad: 1 : 2 for include from file : include from db, 10 : 8 for include from db : eval from db.
Anyway, I do wonder whether a include from db does get cached...

Oh, and the reason I came here was that missing semi-colon driving me crazy

Comment: OK, then ; sorry about that ^^

Comment: How do you deal with dynamically generated code if that file could change on disk and you have multiple processes which can access the file at the same time? You have to guarantee somehow that the file is not read by a process when another process is updating it... Do you think `flock` can solve the issue? Then what else, using `eval` seems "safer" in this case... What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

This lets you include a file assuming file wrappers for includes is on in PHP:

```
function stringToTempFileName($str)
{
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.0', '>=') && strlen($str < (1024 * 512))) {
        $file = 'data://text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode($str);
    } else {
        $file = Utils::tempFileName();
        file_put_contents($file, $str);
    }
    return $file;
}
```

... Then include that 'file.'  Yes, this will also disable opcode caches, but it makes this 'eval' the same as an include with respect to behavior.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @bwoebi in [this answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23681658/229792), the `eval` substitution does not respect the file path context of the included file. As a test case:

`Baz.php`:

```
<?php return __FILE__;
```

`Foo.php`:

```
<?php
echo eval('?>' . file_get_contents('Baz.php',  FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH)) . "\n";
echo (include 'Baz.php') . "\n";
```

Result of executing `php Foo.php`:

```
$ php Foo.php 
/path/to/file/Foo.php(2) : eval()'d code
/path/to/file/Baz.php
```

I don't know of any way to change the `__FILE__` constant and friends at runtime, so I do not think there is any general way to define `include` in terms of `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

Only `eval('?>' . file_get_contents('external.php'));` variant is correct replacement for include.

See tests:

```
<?php
$includes = array(
    'some text',
    '<?php print "some text"; ?>',
    '<?php print "some text";',
    'some text<?php',
    'some text<?php ',
    'some text<?php;',
    'some text<?php ?>',
    '<?php ?>some text',
);

$tempFile = tempnam('/tmp', 'test_');

print "\r\n" . "Include:" . "\r\n";
foreach ($includes as $include)
{
    file_put_contents($tempFile, $include);
    var_dump(include $tempFile);
}

unlink($tempFile);

print "\r\n" . "Eval 1:" . "\r\n";
foreach ($includes as $include)
    var_dump(eval('?>' . $include . '<?php '));

print "\r\n" . "Eval 2:" . "\r\n";
foreach ($includes as $include)
    var_dump(eval('?>' . $include));

print "\r\n" . "Eval 3:" . "\r\n";
foreach ($includes as $include)
    var_dump(eval('?>' . $include . '<?php;'));
```

Output:

```
Include:
some textint(1)
some textint(1)
some textint(1)
some text<?phpint(1)
some textint(1)
some text<?php;int(1)
some textint(1)
some textint(1)

Eval 1:
some textNULL
some textNULL
bool(false)
some text<?phpNULL
bool(false)
some text<?php;NULL
some textNULL
some textNULL

Eval 2:
some textNULL
some textNULL
some textNULL
some text<?phpNULL
some textNULL
some text<?php;NULL
some textNULL
some textNULL

Eval 3:
some text<?php;NULL
some text<?php;NULL
bool(false)
some text<?php<?php;NULL
bool(false)
some text<?php;<?php;NULL
some text<?php;NULL
some text<?php;NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts about the solutions above:

#### Temporary file

Don't. It's very bad for performance, just don't do it. Not only does it drive your opcode cache totally crazy (cache hit never happens + it tries to cache it again every time) but also gives you the headache of filesystem locking under high (even moderate) loads, as you have to write the file and Apache/PHP has to read it.

#### Simple eval()

Acceptable in rare cases; don't do it too often. Indeed it's not cached (poor opcode cache just doesn't know it's the same string as before); at the same time, if your code is *changing each time*, eval is A LOT BETTER than include(), mostly because include() fills up the opcode cache on each call. Just like the tempfile case. It's horrible (~4x slower).

#### In-memory eval()

Actually, eval is *very fast* when your script is already in the string; most of the time it's the disk operation that pulls it back, now surely this depends on what you do in the script but in my very-small-script case, it was ~400 times faster. (Do you have memcached? Just thinking loud) So what include() can't do is *evaluate the same thing twice without file operation*, and this is very important. If you use it for ever-changing, small, memory-generated strings, obviously it's eval to choose - it's many-many times faster to load once + eval again and again than an iterated include().

### TL;DR

- Same code, once per request: **include**
- Same code, several calls per request: **eval**
- Varying code: **eval**

Answer (score 0):

here is my approach.

it creates temporary php file and includes it.

but this way if code you want to run on this function has errors program exits before removing temporary file

so i make an autoclean procedure in function. this way it cleans old temporary files by an timeout everytime function runs. you can set timeout or disable it from options at start of function

i also added ignore error option for solving non removed temporary files. if errors ignored, program will continue and remove temporary file.

also some projects have to disable autoclean because it scans whole directory everytime it runs. it could hurt disk performance.

```
function eval2($c) {
    $auto_clean_old_temporary_files=false; //checks old temporary eval2 files for this spesific temporary file names generated by settings below
    $ignore_all_errors=true; //if you ignore errors you can remove temporary files even there is an error 

    $tempfiledirectory=''; //temporary file directory
    $tempfileheader='eval2_'; // temporary file header 
    $tempfiletimeseperator='__'; // temporary file seperator for time
    $tempfileremovetimeout=200; // temp file cleaning time in seconds

    if ($auto_clean_old_temporary_files===true) {

        $sd=scandir('.'); //scaning for old temporary files 
        foreach ($sd as $sf) {
            if (strlen($sf)>(32+strlen($tempfileheader)+strlen($tempfiletimeseperator)+3)) { // if filename long enough
                $t1=substr($sf,(32+strlen($tempfileheader)),strlen($tempfiletimeseperator)); //searching time seperator
                $t2=substr($sf,0,strlen($tempfileheader)); //searching file header

                if ($t1==$tempfiletimeseperator && $t2==$tempfileheader) { //checking for timeseperator and file name header 
                    $ef=explode('.',$sf); 
                    unset($ef[count($ef)]);//removing file extension 
                    $nsf=implode('.',$ef);//joining file name without extension

                    $ef=explode($tempfiletimeseperator,$nsf);
                    $tm=(int)end($ef); //getting time from filename

                    $tmf=time()-$tm;
                    if ($tmf>$tempfileremovetimeout && $tmf<123456 && $tmf>0) { // if time passed more then timeout and difference with real time is logical 
                        unlink($sf); // finally removing temporary file
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $n=$tempfiledirectory.$tempfileheader . md5(microtime().rand(0,5000)). $tempfiletimeseperator . time() .'.php'; //creating spesific temporary file name
    $c='<?php' . PHP_EOL . $c . PHP_EOL; //generating php content
    file_put_contents($n,$c); //creating temporary file

    if ($ignore_all_errors===true) { // including temporary file by your choise 
        $s=@include($n);
    }else{
        $s=include($n);
    }

    return $s;  

}
```