# How to remove an include file?

Tags: php, include

I have two files that are included in my page. Like this:

```
// mypage.php
include 'script1.php';
include 'script2.php';
```

I need both of them in first, and then I need to remove one of them, something like this:

```
if ($var == 'one') {
      // inactive script1.php file
} else {
     // inactive script2.php file
}
```

That's hard to explain why I need to inactive one of them, I Just want to know, how can I do that? Is it possible to do unlike `include`?

Comment: Please make a little simple example why would you even need this.

Comment: Why not only include the needed file?

Comment: @Rizier123 There are several reasons, one of them is duplicate function name.

Comment: @FoxRider because I need to both of them *in first*.

Comment: Is it possible to do the INCLUDE as part of the IF () {} ELSE{} statement?

Comment: Then you messed something up in your code design. The quick and dirty solution would be to add namespaces in your code, but I think you really have to rethink your code

Comment: @Rizier123 I really can't to rewrite my code again, but `namespaces` is a good idea. thanks

Comment: @Alex if its just for duplicates of function names you can simply use an if statement around your function in the second file thats loaded after the first one and use function_exists('function_name_here') to check if its already loaded.

Comment: If you're having a function name collision you should consider putting those functions inside a [class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php), and then place those classes inside a [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Comment: @BigScar Is it not possible, because I need to both of them in first.

Comment: @DannyBroadbent your solution is fine, But not only because, There are several reasons.

Comment: @Machavity your mean is oop ?

Comment: @Alex See the edit to my answer for an example of how this works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is no, you can't.

The expanded answer is that when you run PHP, it makes two passes. The first pass compiles the PHP into machine code. This is where `include`s are added. The second pass is to execute the code from the first pass. Since the compilation pass is where the `include` was done, there is no way to remove it at runtime.

Since you're having a function collision, here's how to get around that using objects(classes)

```
class Bob {
    public static function samename($args) {

   }
}
class Fred {
   public static function samename($args) {

   }
}
```

Note that both classes have the `samename()` function but they live within a different class so there's no collision. Because they are `static` you can call them like so

```
Bob::samename($somearghere);
Fred::samename($somearghere);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need just the output of either file you could do this

```
ob_start();
include('file1.php');
$file1 = ob_get_contents();

ob_start();
include('file2.php');
$file2 = ob_get_contents();
```

Then later if you need to call them

```
if ($var == 'one') {
    echo $file2;
} else {
    echo $file1;
}
```

Comment: In fact I'm not familiar with `ob_statr();`. anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is something like this:

```
if ($var == 'one') {
      include('script2.php');
} else {
     include('script1.php');
}
```

You can't 'remove' code, you can only choose to not include/execute it in the first place.

Comment: I think OP "needs" both scripts first, that's why he includes it, but then have to delete the included code later, since he has some function name collisions.

Comment: in which case the conditional stuff would have to be put into the individual script files.

Comment: @Rizier123 you right, I need to both scripts first.

Comment: then put the `if ($var)...` stuff inside the scripts to fence off the unwanted stuff.

Comment: If there is duplicated function name, they can't be both included because 2nd script will report fatal error. 
You need go through your script1 and script2 to find which part you really need to be loaded first, and which part you need in condition, split them then use some code like following:

include 'script1-need.php';
include 'script2-need.php';
...
if($var=='one'){
   include ('script2-in-condition.php');
}else{
   include ('script1-in-condition.php');
}

Answer (score 0):

As by your comments you said its because of duplicated function names, i'm assuming you use both files elsewhere separately, but what your trying to achieve now is to merge these files together for a different reason (both files have functions/variables, etc that you need)

If your first file had a function like so my_function:

```
my_function() {
    // code here
}
```

and your second file also had the same named function you can wrap an if statement around it to exclude it:

```
if (!function_exists('my_function')) {
    my_function() {
        // code here
    }
}
```

This way the second file's function wont be available when merging the two files together but using file separately both functions will be available.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of providing options for others that come here, some solutions I've used myself on occasion...

1. If the files you're including, you're including for some function with a return value or some execution that doesn't need to be displayed on the page (such as mailing stuff out), and let's say you *can't* alter either of the target files (let's say they're somebody else's code or part of some highly integrated other piece of software that you *really* don't want to untangle).

A solution is to create a quick and dirty restful interface for both files to pull from them what you need from them, and then call that interface with your program, effectively bypassing the need to include them.

2. A worse method but if your situation is truly desperate, and is truly the route of last resort, and will only work in some cases (for example, will break on namespacing)...

   $bad_idea = file_get_contents("foo.php");

   eval($bad_idea);

   unset($bad_idea);

Again, note, this is an option of last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Though this thread is quite old, the following code may help someone who just want to load variables from php-script files.

I used this for my local processes:

```php
// mypage.php
$file_to_include_1 = 'script1.php';
$file_to_include_2 = 'script2.php';

/**
 * Read file content and evaluate.
 *
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184628/php-equivalent-of-include-using-eval
 */
$file_1_content = '?>' . file_get_contents($file_to_include_1);
eval($file_1_content);
$file_2_content = '?>' . file_get_contents($file_to_include_2);
eval($file_2_content);

if (isset($var) && $var == 'one') {
  /**
   * To deactivate script1.php file unset unnecessary variables, eg.
   */
  unset($var_in_script_1);
  unset($other_var_in_script_1);
} else {
  /**
   * To deactivate script2.php file unset unnecessary variables, eg.
   */
  unset($var_in_script_2);
  unset($other_var_in_script_2);
}
```